# JavaScript behaving weirdly, opening an drop/drag item only 'alert' is put

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have Drag/Drop functionality in my page embedded using YAHOO.js which is initalized at load of the page. When 'alert' is put in the init function, the Drag/Drop is working otherwise
it is not. Using Firebug I had debugged the code and seen when init function is called but not looping through the function when no alert is put.
This function should work when <kbd>ALT</kbd> key is pressed. I am using velocity template engine over JavaScript.
Sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">


var myLogger;
  var dd1, ddTrashCan;  // draggable div objs

  #if ($displayOptions.isDoDragDropJavaScript())
      YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, "load", DD_TestInit);      
  #end

  function display(data) {
   var output = "<div>" + data.text + "</div>";
   element.innerHTML=output;
}
  function DD_TestInit() {
    #if ($showLoggerDiv)
      initLogger();
    #end  
//display("date");
initDragObjects();


}

  function logMsg(strMsg) {
    if (myLogger)
      myLogger.debug(strMsg);
  }
  
  function initDragObjects() {
  
  //alert('---');
  
    if (dd1) dd1.unreg();
    if (ddTrashCan) ddTrashCan.unreg();

    YAHOO.util.DDM.mode = YAHOO.util.DDM.POINT;
    YAHOO.util.DDM.clickTimeThresh = 10;
    
    ## init constant drag objects, draggable div and droppable trash, resp.
    dd1 = new lineSched_Draggable("dragDiv1");  
    ddTrashCan = new lineSched_Droppable("TrashCan");
  }
```

What I had found is whenever I put an alert or call any `window.open()` this works fine.
Any clue whats happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is timer event which is delaying the process.My feeling is that this is a timing issue.  The page is not fully in place when on load.  The alert slows the process down, essentially the page is in place by the time the user clicks Ok on the alert.  Clearly, we can’t deploy the app with an alert.  But, we can look into different places to put the initialization.  We can try to place it the same place I added the timing, when the page receives the last table.  The page should be fully formed at this point and the function should work properly.